# Reading outlook PST file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, pst

I'm looking for a way to read a pst file and use JavaScript to parse it.

I need to read the contacts and the calendar meetings stored in the file.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, of course. Go ahead and try. :) This is not a free coding service, you should research and try first and if you fail, post the code you already have and get help here.

Comment: I have searched for the past 4 days on how this can be done and found nothing. This is why I'm reaching out to the community in hope that someone can lead me in the right direction.

Comment: But what have you tried? What is your starting point? Have you written any code? For example, have you tried reading any file? Have you tried messing with binary content? Everything is possible, this one will probably involve a lot of code if no one wrote a library that parses PST files in JavaScript already (did you search for such a library? I have not, it might exist).

Comment: If you mean reading the PST file directly, forget it. Undocumented AFAIK. You can access things via the API and ActiveX, as Google will show.

Answer (score 1):

PST file format is documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385210(v=office.12).aspx
It is as binary as it gets.

You can use the Outlook Object Model to open a PST file in the current Outlook profile using `Namespace.AddStore`/`AddStoreEx`.

You can also use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author - requires Outlook or the standalone version of MAPI to be installed)  and its [RDOSession.LogonPstStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) or `RDOSession`.[Stores.AddPstStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostores.htm) methods.